# NRF24L01 PA+LNA With Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, nrf24l01+, wireless

I am using the NRF module for remote communucation.I have been many research about nrf but my nrf module is not working This is my tranmistter code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

RF24 radio(7, 8,4000000); // CE, CSN

const byte address[6] = "00001";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  radio.begin();
  radio.openWritingPipe(address);
  radio.setRetries(15,15);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_HIGH);
 
}

void loop() {
  radio.stopListening();
  const char text[32]="Hello world";
  if(radio.write(&text,sizeof(text))){
    Serial.println("Mesaj gönderildi");
  }
  delay(1000);
```

This is my receiver code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

RF24 radio(7, 8,4000000); // CE, CSN

const byte address[6] = "00001";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  delay(400);
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
//  radio.startListening();
   pinMode(10,OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
 const char text[32]="";
  radio.startListening();
  if(radio.available())
  {
    while(radio.available()){
    radio.read(&text[0],sizeof(text[0]));
    Serial.println(text);
    delay(1000);
    }
  }
  delay(5);
   
  
  
}
```

ı tried the setPAlevel min but there is no change.In the transmitter side the write function returns true, but I can't get anything on the receiver side. Also, if I replace the cable connected to miso with the cable connected to mosi on the transmistter side, the write function still returns true. I also used adaptor ams1117

Comment: From your Receiver code: `radio.read(&text[0],sizeof(text[0]));` This looks odd. `sizeof(text[0])` is only one byte.

Comment: I tried this buy now ı am trying gettinstarted examples in arduino.Mosi and miso pins does not connect to microcontroller but output which ı take is this:Tranmission successful.

Comment: Also.I get a radio hardware not responding error when mosi is connected to the arduino mosi pin on the adapter and miso on the adapter is connected to the miso pin on the arduino.When I reverse the cables and connect them, the transmission and reception occur.

Comment: `const char text[32]="";` from the receiver also looks odd because this buffer is supposed to be writable. Anyway, use the code from the thread here: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/simple-nrf24l01-2-4ghz-transceiver-demo/405123 to test your nrf24L01 devices. Most problems with these nrf24L01 devices are related to inadequate power supplies.

Comment: "When I reverse the cables and connect them, the transmission and reception occur." Does this mean that if you cross over MISO and MOSI on the nrf24L01 adapter board,  it all works as expected? I'd be surprised considering the other errors but I suppose it could be a labeling error somewhere.

Comment: Yes.But this only happens at the very beginning. I uploaded the program to Arduino, then I get a radio hardware not responding error. Then I plug the mosi cable on the nrf board into the miso on the arduino. The radio hardware not responding error goes away. Transmissin timed out error comes.Then, after plugging the mosi in the nrf module into the mosi on the arduino, and the miso on the miso on the arduino, the transmission becomes successful.

Answer (score 1):

In the receiver code, you are just reading one byte, as 6v6gt pointed out. Check the library to see [how `read()` works](https://github.com/nRF24/RF24/blob/a028813b285d6cec3090d2c96984bd67a399c52e/RF24.cpp#L408).

If you follow the [getting started example](https://nrf24.github.io/RF24/examples_2GettingStarted_2GettingStarted_8ino-example.html), this is how you should read bytes in the receiver:

```
char text[32];

if (radio.available()) 
{
  uint8_t bytes = radio.getPayloadSize();  // get the size of the payload
  radio.read(&text, bytes);                // fetch payload from FIFO
}
```

Don't use `const` for `text` in the receiver.
Also, you don't need to use `stopListening` and `startListening` in the `loop()`. They should just go to `setup()`.

Comment: Tranmission failed or timed out erros is occured.I tried many things but this error is still continues

Comment: Update the code in the question that you tried last.